# Import error with ruamel.yaml in PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, ruamel.yaml

I am using a function from the `ruamel` package.

```
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import PreservedScalarString
```

But when I built final EXE by PyInstaller, I get this error during the starting application.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 8, in
>      File
>   "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-eo75my\pyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py",
>   line 270, in load_module   File
>   "./build/win32\app\out00-PYZ.pyz\src.utils.utils", line 14, in
>    ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml.scalarstring

I have tried both `PyInstaller` 2.1

What is the problem?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by upgrading to `PyInstaller 3.0` version